# How to call classes and function in type definition file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, type-definition

I'm newbe in typescript and trying to use type definition file with typescript 2.2, (I'm using typescriptlang.org but can't get answer)I have the following type definition file

```
export as namespace mydefinition;

export namespace mynamespace {

  interface Myinterface {
     width: number;
     height: number;
  } 

  class MyClass {
    constructor(attributes?: any);
    addCell(cell: Cell): this; 
 }
}
```

I'm using the following line to import file and it success

```
import { mydefinition } from 'definitionfile';
```

How can I call the classes and function of this definition file?

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading. You specifically can't call classes and functions from within a definition file. It's for defining your classes &c, not calling them. Your question at the end there seems like a better title.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me. You are just missing the initialization of your myclass.

```
import { mydefinition } from './definitionfile';
export class classA implements mydefinition.Myinterface {
    width: number;
    height: number;

    constructor() {
        var test = new mydefinition.MyClass();
        test.addCell("attr");

    }
}
```

Comment: I get ERROR Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'definitionfile' When calling class

Comment: sorry i forgot ./ in front of definitionfile. I changed the code in my answer.  So now it should work.